# C++ Catching split human errors

Tags: c++, vector, split

I am wondering to make a "CMD"-like. I mean that users can enter their commands in the console. The problem I have is that every commands work, but for example, if we don't write every args, the prog crash.
Here is a little piece of the code :

```
 void commande(std::string commandeWanted)
{
    std::vector<std::string> fields;
    boost::split(fields, commandeWanted, boost::is_any_of("|")); // I chose | as spliter
    boost::to_upper(fields[0]);
    //std::cout<< fields[1] << fields[2] <<std::endl;
    if (fields[0] == "STOP")
        stop(fields[1]);
    else if (fields[0] == "DISCONNECT")
        disconnect();
    else if (fields[0] == "CONNECT")
        connect();
    else if (fields[0] == "SEND")
        send(fields[1], fields[2]);
    else if (fields[0] == "clean")
        cleanConsole();
    else if (fields[0] == "HELP")
        displayHelp();
    else
        std::cout << "No command recognized." << std::endl;
}
```

Any idea ? Any suggestion ?
I tried by declaring fields[1] and fields[2], but no way.
The problem is that I can enter "help" this will run the function displayHelp, but for exemple, if I write "send" instead of "send|who|what", this will make the program crash.
Thank you by advance.

Comment: `std::string` in function's argument list makes a copy of the string at function invocation, which is quite heavy operation and is usually unneeded. Take `const std::string&` instead, or, if you want to modify the string, `std::string&`.

Comment: Well, ok. I used Jonathan Mee's solution, and it worked. Thank you all for your help, and have a nice day. For the switching fields and champs, this is because I'm french, and I wrote the program in french. But for the post, I translated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add checks in your code that sufficient fields exist before accessing them.

(Also it looks like you've switched `fields` and `champs` in your `split` call.)

Something like this:

```
void commande(std::string commandeWanted)
{
    std::vector<std::string> fields;
    boost::split(fields, commandeWanted, boost::is_any_of("|")); // I chose | as spliter
    boost::to_upper(fields[0]);
    //std::cout<< fields[1] << fields[2] <<std::endl;
    if (fields[0] == "STOP"){
        if(fields.size >=2)stop(fields[1]);
    }
    else if (fields[0] == "DISCONNECT")
        disconnect();
    else if (fields[0] == "CONNECT")
        connect();
    else if (fields[0] == "SEND"){
        if(fields.size() >= 3)(fields[1], fields[2]);
    }
    else if (fields[0] == "clean")
        cleanConsole();
    else if (fields[0] == "HELP")
        displayHelp();
    else
        std::cout << "No command recognized." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `fields.size() >= 2` before accessing `fields[1]` and so forth for `fields[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you normalize what all your functions look like, you can avoid a lot of the logic duplication and arg size checking:

```
struct Command {
    size_t numArgs;
    std::function<void(std::vector<std::string>)> fun;
};

std::map<std::string, Command> commands = {
    {"STOP", {1, stop}},
    {"DISCONNECT", {0, disconnect}},
    {"SEND", {2, send}},
    // ...
};

// after you split
boost::to_upper(fields[0]);

auto it = commands.find(fields[0]);
if (it != commands.end()) {
    // pop the first one
    fields.erase(fields.begin());

    // check the size
    if (fields.size() != it->second.numArgs) {
        // error: wrong number of args
    }
    else {
        // ok, call me
        it->second.fun(fields);
    }
}
else {
    // command not found
}
```

Unfortunately, C++ has no nice equivalent for the python `*` operator to unpack a vector - but this way at least you know you have all the right args in all the right places, even if all your functions take a vector now.